# player1Turn() won't return desired value

Tags: java

player1Turn() keeps saying that, regardless of what I put in, that temp = 0. temp is supposed to be which pit they chose, but numerically, so I could return temp and use it in the array. Also, I know there needs to be a return statement to complete the method, but for now I'm just trying to get temp to equal what I want it to. Suggestions for the whole thing are welcome, but I'm primarily concerned on player1Turn(). Thanks

```
   import java.util.*;

public class Mancala
{
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  public static void main(String[]args)
  {
    Mancala mancala = new Mancala();
    int[] board = {0,3,3,3,3,3,3,0,3,3,3,3,3,3};
    System.out.print(" ");
    mancala.display(board);
    System.out.print(" ");
    mancala.player1Turn();

  }
  public static void display(int[] board)
{
    System.out.println(" A  B  C  D  E  F");
    System.out.print(" ");
  for(int i = 13; i >=8; i--)
  {
    System.out.print(" "+board[i]+" ");
  }
  System.out.println("\n"+board[0]+"                  "+board[7]);
  System.out.print(" ");
  for(int i = 6; i >=1; i--)
  {
    System.out.print(" "+board[i]+" ");
  }
  System.out.println("\n  G  H  I  J  K  L");
}
public void player1Turn()
{
  int temp = 0;
  System.out.print("Which pit would you like to select? ");
  String pit = input.nextLine();
  {
  if(pit == "A")
    temp = 13;
  else if(pit == "B")
    temp = 12;
  else if(pit == "C")
    temp = 11;
  else if(pit == "D")
    temp = 10;
  else if(pit == "E")
    temp = 9;
  else if(pit == "F")
    temp = 8;
  else
    System.out.print("That is not a valid pit!");
  }
  System.out.print(temp);
}
}
```

Comment: Don't do String equality with `==` rather use `.equals()`

Comment: `if("B".equals(pit)) {...}`